# How to fix Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

Tags: css, laravel, http, laravel-blade

I'm setting up my laravel application and every time I run php artisan serve, it starts a laravel development serve at localhost:8000. Bu when i open the locahost link on the browser, it forces the http to https and logs invalid request (unsupported SSl request). What do you advise me to do to resolve this?

I have tried forcing the HTTPS mod rewrite rule to http:// on the .htaccess file and it still persists.

This is the command line

```
C:\Users\topaz\cashurban>php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:07 2019] 127.0.0.1:60410 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60418 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60419 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60420 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60421 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60423 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60409 [200]: /assets/img/slider-1.jpg
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60425 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60426 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60427 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60411 [200]: /assets/img/slider-2.jpg
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60435 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60437 [200]: /assets/img/slider-3.jpg
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60439 [200]: /assets/img/icon-1-1.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60438 [200]: /assets/img/images/index-Recovereddashboard_03.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60440 [200]: /assets/img/icon-2-1.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60442 [200]: /assets/img/icon-3-1.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:08 2019] 127.0.0.1:60447 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60448 [200]: /assets/img/tor1.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60450 [200]: /assets/img/tor2.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60452 [200]: /assets/img/tor3.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60455 [200]: /assets/img/images/visa.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60453 [200]: /assets/img/images/remita.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60454 [200]: /assets/img/images/master-card.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60460 [200]: /assets/img/images/verve.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60461 [200]: /assets/img/images/indexpartners_11.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60462 [200]: /assets/img/images/bank-branches.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60463 [200]: /assets/img/images/indexpower_03.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60464 [200]: /assets/img/images/paystack.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:60465 [200]: /assets/img/images/chams.png
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:10 2019] 127.0.0.1:60468 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Thu Aug 22 23:06:10 2019] 127.0.0.1:60469 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
```

this is the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #Force Https

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #Api Redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    #RewriteRule ^/api$ api.%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    #GZip Compression
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
      #mod_gzip_on Yes
      #mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
      #mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|xml|json|pl)$
      #mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
      #mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
      #mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
      #mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
      #mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>

    #php_value auto_prepend_file /home/example_project/public_html/error_handler_slack.php
    php_value auto_prepend_file error_handler_slack.php
</IfModule>
```

I expect that it serves on http://localhost and not https://localhost as it is currently redirecting

Comment: Please check the `APP_URL` in the `.env` file should be something like this: `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: @dparoli I made sure of that, even in the config/app.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this later, just in case anyone has a similar problem in the future, I discovered the AppServiceProvider class had a register method where a security interception middleware was registered to force every HTTP request to HTTPS. So I wrote an if-else logic to allow this only on production since my localhost had no SSL certificate.

in app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php

look for the register() method, then implement the logic by checking whether the app is local or not. The isLocal() method checks your .env file for APP_ENV variable and returns true if it is local, so you reconfirm again that, that is set to local and be sure to clear any previous configuration cache.

```
//check that app is local
if ($this->app->isLocal()) {
//if local register your services you require for development
    $this->app->register('Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider');
} else {
//else register your services you require for production
    $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as you had. I put the code above in register method, but can you explain what is this class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider'? I keep getting error that is not defined

Comment: @Marko If you don't have barryvdh Debugbar installed in your project, then you should comment it in the code.

Comment: For those that says it is not defined  class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' you should check that is composer.json, and so do composer update, or install it from : composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev

Comment: Hi I have the same problem but with laravel 4.2, where I can find this AppServiceProvider in this old version??

Comment: @Tarek Bakri let's see your setup and then I can know how to help.

Comment: Thank you @zaghadon this fix my problem using Laravel 9, as well as my problem on session error 419

Comment: In addition I fixed mine using the debugging tool of Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider

Answer (score 12):

1. First make sure the APP_URL in the .env file is something like
   this: **APP_URL=http://localhost** or **http://127.0.0.1:8000**
2. Change **APP_ENV=production** to **APP_ENV=development**
3. Then run **php artisan serve** again

> if above method doesn't work

Edit the /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file:
**URL::forceScheme('https');** to **URL::forceScheme('`http`');**

and run the application again

Comment: This solved my issue of not being able to connect to Laravel Dusk and Selnium as it was forcing https. Tnx!

Answer (score 5):

> This is how I fixed my Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

#### NB: All these changes must be worked on from your project *root* directory

1. Delete all files inside the **bootstrap\cache** folder (except the **.gitignore** file, that is if you have one)
2. Delete the **vendor** folder
3. Type `composer install` or `composer update` in command line terminal to install or update the necessary files and configurations back

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by disabling cache:

**Step 1:**

config\cache.php

```
'stores' => [
        'none' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],
    ],
```

**Step 2:**

app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

Add at the top

```
use Illuminate\Cache\NullStore;
use Cache;
```

Add in boot() method

```
Cache::extend('none', function ($app) {
            return Cache::repository(new NullStore);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel Framework 7+** you need to edit the `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file: Update

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

to

```
URL::forceScheme('`http`');
```

Then clean cache using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and run application.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `.env` file,
change `APP_ENV=production`   to `APP_ENV=development`

Then run `php artisan serve` again

Answer (score 2):

I have to change the

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```

to

```
URL::forceScheme('http');
```

AND

`serve --port` and my issue is resolved.

```
php artisan serve --port=8002
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it by changing the APP_URL=http://**localhost** to APP_URL=http://**127.0.0.1** in the .env file

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to share my experience just in case it helps someone. Even I got the same error. This is how I solved it.

I added the following in `.env` file.

> APP_SSL=false

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything recommended above and nothing worked. Here is how I got past the problem:

My browser is trying to access https://localhost:8000. Simply changing to http://localhost:800 on my browser address bar solved the problem. Spent days tinkering on this problem and I believe leaving this answer here would help someone someday

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by changing **APP_URL=http://localhost** to **APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/** in '.env' file.

Answer (score 1):

Find out that you are not working on the same project on another browser/tab.

I had a similar issue. I was already working on my Laravel project before I opened another window to work on something else. I was working on a Nodejs project but in the same VScode and the terminal was for it and the port number was 8080. I closed the browser tab of the node project to return to the Laravel project to start php artisan serve again (e.g two different browser windows but one terminal) and I started having that problem.

I just closed the second browser tab and that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine using @zaghadon solution using Laravel 9, and put little modification,

On AppServiceProvider.php located at app\Providers\ inside boot function:

```
if ($this->app->isLocal()) 
{
    $this->app['request']->server->set('http', true);
}
```

Comment: If you were registering one conditional, I believe you should @Kam Dane answer. You don't need the if-else block in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response of @zaghadon.

best solution is just to use one condition :

Change must be done on file : app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function register()
{
    //check that app is local
    if (!$this->app->isLocal()) {
        //else register your services you require for production
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I was registering Barryvdh Debugbar if the app was Local, so the if-else block is justified. Otherwise, your answer is correct all the same.

Comment: the if-else make sense ... legit !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing `http://localhost:8000` to `localhost:8000`

[Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/invalid-request-unsupported-ssl-request-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but my answer may solve someone's problem.
On the local development server, if you don't need to send an HTTPS request,

Try changing your URL from

```
https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

to this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Make sure your APP_URL in .env is set to http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: Whilst you did say "if you _don't_ need to send an HTTPS request...", this is pretty obvious that the question is asking for SSL support on a PHP local server. HTTPS is an absolute *must* and requirement for testing secure third-party environments that demand you must use a local HTTPS environment (and it's better for replicating live environments, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are try to change URL from **http to https** on the localhost to fix this problem undo changes that it will change http to https and writing the URL by this way

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0):

For new users coming here.

In my case, I had to go into `app\Http\Kernel.php` and comment on this line

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\ForceHttps::class,
    ],
```

You can clear the config using the `php artisan config:clear` command afterwards.