# Unsupported SSL request - Php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel-5

After running command `php artisan serve` it prompt **Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000** but after running the same address in browser, its showing error `127.0.0.1:49938 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)`

.env file

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I have already cleared cache, view, config, routes

Comment: Are you visiting the site via HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617864/how-to-fix-invalid-request-unsupported-ssl-request)

Answer (score 3):

> Add below code in your **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** file

```
public function boot()
{
   if (!$this->app->isLocal()) {
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
   }
}
```