# Laravel 8 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-8

I cloned a project from https://github.com/iluminar/goodwork after doing install, migrate, seed, etc I ran it using php artisan serve and when open the link http://127.0.0.1:8000 the terminal log said that Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request). If i change the url from https into http it worked, but after click login it became https again.

I tried this solution but seems doesnt work for me [How to fix Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617864/how-to-fix-invalid-request-unsupported-ssl-request)

anyone can help me what should I do?

Comment: did you check AppServiceProvider file?

Comment: ya, i checked that file, here is the code https://github.com/iluminar/goodwork/blob/master/app/Base/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: do you have a key name `APP_PROTOCOL` in your .env file?

Comment: yes, it was https, then I changed into http and, but the project cant run correctly

Comment: what's the problem? or error provided by laravel?

Comment: no, the project cant open any url except the default (127.0.0.1:8000). if i force open url (ex:127.0.0.1:8000) it show an error from laravel said Unable to locate Mix file: /js/users/settings.min.js.