# Laravel - Access For Devices on Local Network

Tags: laravel, networking, server, localhost

I've developed a web-application and I'm having trouble hosting it through a server, in order to give access to other users connected over the Local Network.

WINDOWS SERVER 2012
LARAVEL
PHP 7.2
NODE
MYSQL

When running the web application over localhost with the following command all files load correctly. (CSS, images etc..)

```
php artisan serve
```

However, when I've tried running the application over my ip address, no files load correctly and console logs the following errors for APIs net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

```
php artisan serve --host='my-ip' --port=8080
```

Command Prompt shows following error

```
Error Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
```

Testing was through Chrome Web Browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Have a good day :)

Comment: Maybe this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617864/how-to-fix-invalid-request-unsupported-ssl-request) will help.

Comment: @MahdiSamavi I've already tried adding that code to my register method in AppServiceProvider class but no luck, same issue

Comment: Have you ever tried this `\URL::forceScheme('https');`?

Comment: @MahdiSamavi I have also included that in boot method in AppServiceProvider class but still same errors